# A word or expression for someone who had a very important influence in your life?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How to say that someone had a very important influence in your life?

I know the word "milestone" which is mostly used for events.. Is there any similar word that can be used for people?

Thanks!

Comment: The common word to refer to a person is "influence".

Comment: The "milestone" might be called a *turning point* in your life.

Comment: @Jim can we use "turning point" referring to a person?

Comment: No, the person is not a turning point.  You would say something like, "Meeting Dave represented a turning point in my life."

Comment: @Scott I think your comment should be an edit.

Comment: @bib: Why would it be an edit (to the question)? I was putting it forward as a potential answer, but I think I won't, since the OP shows no signs of liking it.

Comment: @Scott Well, his question didn't really scan, and, as you said, *influence* is the right word. Maybe it should be the answer, or an inspiration for other answers. Obviously, none springs to mind since I am chatting with you rather than answering the question.

Comment: @bib you said one right there; the OP could refer to this person as an *inspiration*. Could even refer to many, i.e. "My first inspirational mentor", "My second inspiration.." etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call them an [*inspiration*](http://gog.is/define+inspiration).

Answer (score 2):

An individual who had a very important influence in your life could be just about anyone depending on the circumstances. A word or expression for that person could be mentor, confidant, counselor, adviser, teacher, coach, guardian angel, or the devil himself.

Comment: well I want to tell the person how important is he/she to me. I should have made this clear in the question probably.